# How to concatenate multiple columns where value may be be NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pull a query from multiple columns from a table. Some rows will have data in one column, others will have two, three, and even four.

I tried to use this construct:

SELECT person_uid,('(' || major ||  NVL((',' ||second_major), '') ||  NVL((',' ||third_major), '') ||  NVL(',' ||fourth_major, '') || ')' ) AS MAJORS FROM academic_study

But the result would be like this:

6231    (BUMG,BUMK,,)

19091   (TDST,TDPG,,)

I need the parentheses, but not the trailing commas.

I could potentially strip out the extra commas in post processing, but I would prefer to do it in the SQL. I am using ORACLE.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data model!  Storing multiple columns with parallel data is awkward.

One method is:

```
select person_uid,
       ( '(' || major ||
             (case when second_major is not null then ',' || second_major end) ||
             (case when third_major is not null then ',' || third_major end) ||
             (case when fourth_major is not null then ',' || fourth_major end) ||
         ')'
       )
```